Why on-screen keyboard doesn't display anymore after I open YouTube video in fullscreen mode from WKWebview for iOS18
I create iPhone app and run it on iPad with iOS18. I have UIViewController which contains WKWebView to open YouTube video as code below. When I open this screen (YoutubeViewController) and then tap on video, it would display video in fullscreen. I close fullscreen and then close this screen (YoutubeViewController) and go to other screens which contains UITextField or UITextView. I tap on UITextField or UITextView but on-screen keyboard doesn't display. I try to debug on observer func for UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification but it is not called. I also found that UIScreen.main.bounds get changed to be iPad size.
If I terminate app and launch it again and then open screens which have UITextField or UITextView without opening video in fullscreen mode on YoutubeViewController then on-screen keyboard is displayed normally.
Anyone found this problem before? This problem occurs on iPhone app and run on iPad with iOS18 only.
import UIKit
@preconcurrency import WebKit

class YoutubeViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    
    private var webView: WKWebView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction))
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView?.isOpaque = false
        webView?.backgroundColor = .white
        webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        webView?.uiDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView!)
        
        let youtubeHtml = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    .wrapper {
                        padding: 40px;
                    }
                    .embed-container {
                        position: relative;
                        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
                        height: 0;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        max-width: 100%;
                    }
                    .embed-container iframe,
                    .embed-container object,
                    .embed-container embed {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="embed-container">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aAkMkVFwAoo?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="youtube-iframe"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var tag = document.createElement("script");
                    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
                    
                    var player;
                    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                        player = new YT.Player("youtube-iframe", {
                            events: {
                                "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    
                    var started = false;
                    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !started) {
                            if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler) {
                                window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage("YouTubePlayerStarted");
                            }
                            started = true;
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
        """
        
        webView?.loadHTMLString(youtubeHtml, baseURL: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com"))
    }
    
    @objc func doneAction() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        guard let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }
        
        let cred = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
            guard let messageBody = message.body as? String, messageBody == "YouTubePlayerStarted" else {
                return
            }
        }
    }

}

